# How do I configure Swift ACLs?

Tags: juju, openstack

How do I configure a swift container to allow public (anonymous read) unauthenticated access to all objects?

Answer (score 2):

You can set it via curl, this page has examples:

- http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-object-storage/1.0/content/special-metadata-acls.html